# Is there a word that stands for, "someone who has bought this item"?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to differentiate between two different types of buyers that will show up in a website's search results. I have one type of buyer who purchases a large number of items but has not bought the specific item the website user is searching for. This customer is called a "Authorized distributor". However I need a way to describe, with one or two words, a buyer who has bought the specific item that the website user is searching for.

Is there a word that says this about a buyer?

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  Can you explain a bit more about why such a difference matters, and who it matters to?  (Normally I would expect an authorized distributor to be one from whom I, as a retailer, can buy the product, regardless of whether they have bought the product before or not; if they don't currently have it in stock they should get it so that they can then fill my order.)

Comment: What about just writing X purchaser/purchaser of X, where X is the product in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**purchaser**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/purchaser)

> a person who buys

As in:

> We did a search for purchasers of x item(s) on our website

Comment: I like this idea of using the term "purchaser" for the customer who has actually purchased the item being searched for.

Answer (score -1):

Two commonly-used terms are "end-user" and "consumer".

Manufacturers sell many, perhaps thousands of the same item to authorized distributors, usually at a wholesale price. The authorized distributor then resells the goods, as few as one at a time, at a retail price to the end-user or consumer. The manufacturer of the items holds the authorized distributor responsible to deliver a high-quality product to the end-user or consumer.

Consumer is from the verb "to consume" which means to eat or to drink. The usage of consumer broadened to mean a person who uses the goods or the services until they are gone or until they no longer function. For instance, grocery consumers, utility consumers, even automobile consumers. Consumer indicates one person or one household.

End-user is a term that became popular for consumers of intellectual property, such as end-users of software. End-user also expanded for consumers of video games and other products. End-user is synonymous with consumer.

Comment: Could the person who voted this answer down please explain why the answer is not correct?